# Which font is better to optimise the speed of my website designed on WIX platform?

Tags: seo, web-development, wix

I have developed a website using WIX platform. The loading speed is very slow it takes around 6-10 seconds to load a speed. Few things I can not optimize since wix uses many third party applications and do allow any changes. I was trying to use the best font which will enhance my loading speed and helps in reduce bounce rate.

Currently using Camphor family fonts, I am planning to use Roboto and Lato now. Will it help me to increase performance?

Comment: Why do you think one custom font is going to be faster than another?   If you want a fast site, don't specify the font used and let the browser use their default that doesn't need to be downloaded.  From what I have seen, Wix sites get slower and slower the more pages you have.   For site speed, it is best just not to use Wix.

Comment: "The loading speed is very slow it takes around 6-10 seconds to load a speed." Did you do a comprehensive study (starting with the developer tools in your browser that should be able to display the list of queries made, their schedule and time for completion) that explain why you arrived at your conclusion? Also easy way to test, just copy your page, edit it to remove all remote fonts use, and see how fast it loads.

Answer (score 1):

No, they shouldn't affect the speed. Even if you use every single font on Wix, there will be no speed change. However, if you upload your own fonts, they will **slow the site down**, so be careful.

There's this thing called `font-face`, which is a CSS thing. This embeds the font in the HTML. Wix embeds all their fonts in the HTML, so this could be what slows it down.

However, if you upload your own fonts, you will get a slower service because there's more fonts.